# Rails 3 Sandbox Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

In Rails 2 you're able to run

```
script/console --sandbox
```

so you can play with production data and not accidentally break anything.

I can't seem to find the equivalent command for Rails 3. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Easy, type in:

```
bundle exec rails c -s
```

and that is it.

```
$ bundle exec rails c --help
Usage: console [environment] [options]
    -s, --sandbox                    Rollback database modifications on exit.
        --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the console.
        --irb                        DEPRECATED: Invoke `/your/choice/of/ruby script/rails console` instead
```

It is simple, but, sometimes, if you are not running `rails` executable using `bundle exec`, it may, or may not, result in an error. In order to avoid this, **ALWAYS** use `bundle exec`.

To quote [bundler page](http://gembundler.com/) (if not documentation):

> In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if
>   the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not
>   pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle.
>
> However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain.
>   Even if it looks like it works, it may not work in the future or on
>   another machine.

Comment: As simple as that indeed :) Thanks! There's obviously something more going on on my server as when I ran rails c --help I get some vomit error...