# Can I open a rails console in read-only mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, irb

I'm used to interrogating my rails db via `script/console`.

But in some instances I need to be exceptionally careful about not changing data, so I'd like to be able to open the console in a read-only mode.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See this question

[Can I specify in database.yml that a rails environment should have readonly access to the DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043956/can-i-specify-in-database-yml-that-a-rails-environment-should-have-readonly-acces)

```
script/console --sandbox
```

Comment: That's not really "read-only" (but it's as close as you can get), since database changes will be made, although they will be rolled back (hopefully successfully) when the console exits. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881646/rails-3-sandbox-console) also.

Comment: @Zabba I agree it's not a perfect solution

Comment: Thanks!  That'll do for my purposes.

Comment: Nowadays with rails 3 and 4 the command the sandbox console can be accessed via `rails c -s`.